# How to push files from Jenkins to GIT

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins Job that copy files from remote servers to local Jenkins machine.

How I want to push that files to a GIT Repo, to update the repo with ne files from remote server.

How can I do this ?

Comment: What did you try and what has gone wrong? Why don't you just copy the files to the repo, replace them and then push?

Comment: There is a section where you can write and run bash/python or whatever commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your current build has a clone of the target repo in `${WORKSPACE}`, it should be enough to run the following within a `Execute shell` build step after you copied your files:

```
cd "${WORKSPACE}"
git status # should show <file> as changed or unversioned

git add <file>
git commit -m "Added file with automated Jenikins job"
git push
```